# Powershell Silent switches

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I am running into some issues with writing this Powershell script. When I run this, it is supposed to be silent. Every switch I try continues to prompt click "install". Could anyone shed some light? Am I missing a switch?

```
   if (Test-Path $Temp_Path) {
        Write-Host "File Exists"
        Start-Process -FilePath $TeamMate_Downloader -Verb runAs -ArgumentList '/s /v/qn'-PassThru
   }
   else {
       Write-Host "File does not Exist"

   }
```

Comment: depends on the program trying to be installed. Does it accept those switches? You're also missing a `-` in `-PassThru`.

Comment: I have the - in the original code. I must of deleted it on accident when i was formating it in here.

Comment: I am not sure if it accepts switches. It's an add-in used by a 3rd party application.

Comment: You've kind of begun in the wrong end. Does `<installer> /s /v /qn` work as expected/desired in an elevated cmd? That, or, checking the official download site for info...

Comment: The results are the same. It prompts "install" but it skips the rest of the install app process and does the rest silently. So it like mostly works but for some reason, you need to click install.

Comment: `it is supposed to be silent` - According to what/who? Too much guess work here, is the application called "TeamMate Downloader", "TeamMate <other>" or something else? What happens if you double click the installer, does it say "Install" and then does everything quietly?

Comment: If you click the installer normally, it will prompt install and proceed to ask you to click through the installation. I am going to email the vendor and see if it is indeed supported.

Comment: Is this installer an MSI file? If so you can run `msiexec /?` to see how to do it. Something like `msiexec /i:installer.msi /qn /norestart /l*v:verbose.log` ...if everything is in your working directory.